# MongoBulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, schema

So, I read all the answers to my problem on Stackoverflow and other websites and none of the solutions have helped me.

The following is the exact error -

`MongoBulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: "aaaaaaa@gmail.com" }`

Below is my schema -

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 2,
      max: 50,
    },

    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 2,
      max: 50,
    },

    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      max: 50,
      unique: true,
    },

    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 5,
    },

    picturePath: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },

    friends: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
    location: String,
    occupation: String,
    viewedProfile: Number,
    impressions: Number,
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

export default User;
```

I tried dropping the index `email_1` that is causing the problem from the website (graphically).

[image]

However, that doesn't seem to do anything. And `email_1` is created every time I try to run my server.

Also, I checked my database and found that there is no duplicate `'aaaaaaa@gmail.com'` email in my database. I manually uploaded my some starting data to my db for testing purposes of the app I am trying to build.

I am reluctant on deleting my entire database because IF this were to happen to me in production, deleting the entire db would not be an option. I want to fix the issue.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You're asking the index to be created based on this line in your schema `unique: true,`

Comment: For `string` in `mongoose.Schema`, should it be `min`/`max` or [`minLength`/`maxLength`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#string-validators)?

Comment: @user20042973 I don't quite understand. Can you please elaborate what you are trying to ask/tell?

Comment: Are you performing any operations with `upsert` that might repeat the `email` field?

Comment: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/unique

Answer (score 1):

Right so, I figured out the error.

Whenever you're working with "sample data", make sure you're complying to the restrictions you set in your schema.

In my case, I was trying to add the same sample data to my db every time I ran the server. I essentially forgot to comment out the part of my code where I was inserting my sample data to my db. All I had to do was comment out that part of the code and the server was live again!